# How to make an item unavailable for other users while a user is viewing it in a php website?

Tags: database-design, concurrency

I am in the process of developing a website for a driving school that will also act as a management app.

One requisite is that at some point the student can choose a day for the driving lesson to take place out of a list of possible schedules.

Since there are many users that could be watching the same schedule I want to be able to make that particular day and hour unavailable to other users as soon as someone is watching for that particular time

It should work just like the travel websites. When you select a flight, that flight becomes locked to other users so they cannot buy it over you and will be available after 5 minutes if you don't buy it.

I understand the concept but I'm not getting how this information is processed and what steps should I do in order to acomplish it.

I need to understand if it works by some triggering in the database, that when activated will set the item to a "unavailable" state and when that timer stops it resets it to the previous state, or if its something that should be done in the application itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to use any timer (which would require a background process, which would increase the complexity of the system).

As soon as the user performs an action which should set aside the element (a ticket, a booking, a time slot, whatever), you assign to this element a pair containing the user and the current time.

When other users access the same element, the application will compute the difference between the “set aside” time stored for this element, and compare it to the actual time. If the difference is, say, superior to 5 minutes, the element can be shown. If not, the element is hidden/blocked.

UX-wise, it's up to you to decide whether you need to show all the time slots and display the ones already booked differently, in order to show that they are unavailable, or if you will only show available slots.

Note that, [as highlighted by amon](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/336025/how-to-make-an-item-unavailable-for-other-users-while-a-user-is-viewing-it-in-a/336026?noredirect=1#comment718120_336026), you'll also need to remember, for each user, the element she/he have set aside, in order to avoid a situation where the user unintentionally blocks multiple slots for a period of time.

If you are using a relational database, this means:

- Adding a foreign key `TimeSlot.BookedBy` referencing `User` table.
- Setting an **unique index** on `TimeSlot.BookedBy`: we don't want a user to be able to book multiple time slots.
- Adding `TimeSlot.BookTime: datetime` column which will store the time where the booking happened.

Comment: A very elegant solution. Of course, the hold on that time slot should be cleared as soon as the user switches to another slot or when the reservation signup flow is aborted, so each user may only have at most one active hold on a time slot. Otherwise, a user browsing through possible slots might accidentally deny service to other users.

Comment: Hmm I see. That is actually a good point and a nice solution. It is far from what I've imagined

Comment: I'm curious, how would your solution be affected by changing to or from daylight saving time?

Comment: @Vincent: The trick is to store all your database times in UTC.

Comment: @Brian Thanks! I'm not too familiar with dates and timezones, for some reason I thought that UTC was also affected by DST.

Comment: Oh damn. Sorry, I had the screen  in dual screen mode and was unable to read the complete answer. Thank you very much for the help and detailed answer.

Comment: @Mr.Toxy: you're welcome. And I edited the question since your first comment, so the question you've originally read and the one which appears now are indeed different.